# Laravel 5.4.36 - Deleted controller now having problems

Tags: visual-studio, composer-php, laravel-5.4, controllers

I created a second controller in an attempt to imitate a PostsController I learnt off the Laravel From Scratch tutorial on YouTube in order to try and change the redirect folders in the public function etc to a different view's folder and see what happens but it was clashing with the original controller so I ended up deleting it along with its route::resource code.

Now when I try to go back to my original "Posts" page in the browser i get an ErrorException reading:

include(C:\wamp64\www\lsapp\vendor\composer/../../app/Http/Controllers/ShowsController.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory

I imagine this is a composer issue and wondering if I could get some insight on how to fix it! Thanks

Answer (score 3):

So I figured it out and all I had to do is run the `composer dump-autoload` command in the integrated terminal.

fixed!